# Find which lines in a file changed between two branches if the file is generated by code

Tags: git, testing, continuous-integration

I am looking for the most efficient way to detect changes in a single file between two git branches (current branch and master) if the file is not directly stored in the repository, but generated by running the script. I am trying to avoid changing branches to do so, if possible and would like this to work locally and on the CI.

The motivation behind it is to have a better control of which tests to run on the feature branch. I would like to be able to trigger different tests depending on which lines in the file changed.

One idea I have is to create an automatic job on master that would store the new version of the file whenever someone merges something into it and then on a feature branch I could just generate the file and compare with its master version.

Another idea is to instead of comparing with master I could just check if that file version was tested. I could have a database storing the test results with enough information to be able to detect what changed in my generated file and whether it was tested or not.

I would very much appreciate any help, pointers.
Thanks

Comment: What prevents you doing so? git show can give you the file contents without checking out and there is also git diff which can compare a file at revision against a file on disk.

Comment: The issue is that the file is not directly stored in git, but is generated from the source code.